# Is out of control adjective?

Tags: adjectives, syntactic-analysis

> It makes that difficult and out of control.

There is a pattern *make + object + adjective* that I'm aware of, but I cannot understand how *out of control* is adjective.

Does *out of control* function as an adjective or adverb?
I think *out* here is an adverb not a preposition, so, if I’m not mistaken, it is not a prepositional phrase.

Comment: The idiomatic preposition phrase "out of control" can't be used predicatively, as in your example. "Make" is used here as a complex-intransitive verb ("cause to be") and  it resists PPs like "out of control" as PC. Thus "It makes that out of control" is borderline at best.   The adjective "difficult" is fine, though.

Answer (score 2):

"Out of control" as a phrase is grammatically identical to "out of bounds" or "out of the question"; all of them mean that the subject lies outside the scope of something, so "out" is a preposition.

Therefore, "out of control" is an adjectival phrase, grammatically similar to "uncontrolled" (i.e., the opposite of "controlled," which is an adjective).

Comment: ^ for "adjectival phrase"

Comment: @Jas.MacOisdealbha  "Out of control" is actually an idiomatic PP (preposition phrase) headed by the preposition "out".  But it's ungrammatical with this use of "make" ("cause to be").

Comment: @BillJ yeah, that too =)